# splitting a string into parts without cutting the words : Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Suppose let the string be "This is a long string that I want to split"
 and the fixed length be 10.If the size of the word makes the part of the string to exceed the fixed the length then that should be considered into the next part of the string

Now the result I am looking for is :

"This is a ", "long" , "string " , "that I want" , "to split"

I have been searching a lot for this functionality but couldn't get it right

Comment: What it the rule to split the string ? Why are you taking *This is a* and not only *This is* ?

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33012945/2025923)?

Comment: i am trying to make it work with conditional string manipulations but in vain.

Comment: But "that I want" has 11 character!

Comment: @YasharAliabasi yea, should be "that I " sry for that