# How to add counter for counting words in a sentence - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

```
 function countTheWords() {
    var word = "";
    var num;
    num = num + 1;
```

How do i add a counter to this? I'm trying to count how many words there are in a sentence. 
I have a test next week that I am studying for and I am stuck on this.
I know that what I have is wrong, so please guide me on how I can count the number of words in a sentence.

```
    do {
    word = prompt("Enter a sentence one word at a time. Enter exit to finish your sentence.");
    word = word + 1;
    }while(word != "exit"); 


    document.write("There are: " + word + " words in your sentence");
}
```

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679576/counting-words-in-string

Comment: Don't use `document.write`.

Answer (score 0):

To test how many words are in a sentence you could do something like:

```
 function wordCount(str){
   return str.match(/\s/g).length+1;
 }
```

In real practice you won't use prompt or alert, but this might help too:

```
 var sen = prompt('Please enter a sentence.');
 alert('There are '+wordCount(sen)+' words in your sentence!');
```

Comment: Seriously? She seems like she has just started with programming and you are using regexes?

Answer (score 0):

you can split based on word separator for example " " and new lines.

an example:

```
var str = "sample sentence"; // or var str=prompt("Enter a sentence")
var x = str.split(" ");      // use newline or any separator if reqd
document.write(x.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is by using Regular Expressions. For every word entered, check for the word `exit` in it just by doing:

```
/exit/.test(word);
```

This will return a `boolean` value that you can test.

Here is the updated code:

```
var wordCount = 0;

do {
  word = prompt("Enter a sentence one word at a time. Enter exit to finish your sentence.");
  wordCount++;
}while(/exit/.test(word) === false); 


document.write("There are: " + wordCount + " words in your sentence");
```

Read up: [Regular Expressions - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

You can make use of arrays to count the words:

```js
var sentence = "This is a sentence.";

var wordCount = sentence.split(' ').length;

console.log(wordCount);  // check your browser's Javascript console to see the count
```

Comment: The *test* method returns true or false, so `while (!/exit/.test(word))` seems more appropriate, but `while (word != 'exit')` is a lot simpler and is an exact match, whereas the former tests for "exit" anywhere in *word*. A *while* condition is not terminated by a semicolon. In the above, it represents an empty statement.

Comment: @RobG I just wanted to be more specific to the newbie OP :) by saying `/exit/.test(word) === false`. Since the `.prompt()` is asking for a sentence, i believe it would be more appropriate to check for `exit` in the whole sentence.

Comment: @RobG MDN has an example where `do .. while` ends with `;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while

Comment: Hmm… MDN isn't an authority, but [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-do-while-statement) seems to agree. But I can't find a case where it's needed, let me think about it…now I want to know where it's required.

Comment: I can't find a case where the semicolon is necessary to prevent ambiguity. So while strictly it's required, in practice it seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
function wordCounter(word){
   return word.split(' ').length
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
function countWords(sentence) {
    //Creates an array of all of the words and gets the array's length
    return sentence.split(" ").length;
}

alert(countWords("A very simple function can save lots of time")); // 9
```

Comment: I was writing this when there were no other posts. Sorry if I 'stole' your answer