# How can I evenly space wrapped text across multiple lines using CSS?

Tags: css, responsive-design, word-wrap

When I make some horizontally centered text on my website, when the text wraps, it looks like this:
[image]

But I want this text to be distributed evenly, like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this in a manner suitable for responsive web design?

Comment: Increase the **font-size** to match the design and have the container width equal. It will be same as what you want.

Comment: If you want those left and right spaces to be covered, use the CSS **text-align: justify;**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I evenly balance text over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875725/how-can-i-evenly-balance-text-over-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 0):

You can use break tag.

```
<br/>
```

tags if you don't.

And if you do then just try increasing the font properties, as given below:

```
text-align: center; 
text-align: justify;
```

This is going to work just as fine.

Comment: The `<br>` tag is not suitable for responsive web design where screen size is not consistent. The text is already centered, and changing it to justified wouldn't do anything to fix the problem.