# How can I balance text lines in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, textview

I am trying to achieve something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875725/how-can-i-evenly-balance-text-over-multiple-lines) in flutter.

Take the following text for example;

> Some long text that should be displayed in
>
> two lines.

I want it to be displayed like this;

> Some long text that should
>
> be displayed in two lines.

I can't simply do this by putting a 'new line character' `\n` to the string manually because it will be a dynamic string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RichText, or try to add "\n" operator. So it should look like "Some long text that should\nbe displayed in two lines."

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention that the string will be dynamic. So I can't manually insert \n character to it.