# How to get count of word in element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rich-text-editor, word-count

Hi I would like to do a Word Count in my RTE (Rich Text Editor) with javascript can also use with jquery. But it should not count the html tags and repeating white spaces.

Sample Text:

`<h1>Hello World</h1> <p> This  is   Good!!!</p> answer <h2>thanks! </h2>`

The javascript should display 7 only.

Is there any javascript code for this and that is also fast to calculate the Word Count?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

What if the sample text is this: `<p>11 22&nbsp; 33</p><p>44</p>5<br></div>`
The javascript should display 5 only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting words in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679576/counting-words-in-string)

Comment: @YoYo hmmm yup but how about the html tags if I check the text?

Comment: You can use the link YoYo has provided but before counting the word you can use `.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")` and `.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');` The first one will strip out any HTML tags and the second one will remove and double spaces ect....

Comment: use `.text()` to avoid html tags

Comment: Hi @NewToJS how about if this is the Sample Text: <p>11 22&nbsp; 33</p><p>44</p>5<br></div>

Comment: @howardtyler Then add a `replace.('&nbsp', ' ');`

Comment: @NewToJS I still get 3 using the mohammad's code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get text content of element. You can get text of element using [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). Then you need to remove additional space of text. [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) and `replace(/[\s]+/g, " ")` remove additional space in text. Now you can convert text to word using [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

```js
var length = $(".text").text().trim().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").split(" ").length;
console.log(length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
    <h1>Hello World</h1> 
    <p> This  is   Good!!!</p> 
    answer 
    <h2>thanks! </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: adding explanation will help better than providing just the code

Comment: But I think it would be a good idea to explain the steps for those who have never used javascript but wish to learn from answers rather than just copy/paste. Example `trim()` will mean nothing to someone new to using javascript, it's not likely someone will just know that `trim()` removes whitespace from both sides of a string or understand what `/[\s]+/` is doing....

Comment: Much better with the explanation! Now this can help multiple people who face the same question/problem. +1 for a detailed explanation with reference links to the relevant documentation.

Comment: yes thanks @Mohammad for this with explanation and also to others supporters! :)

Comment: @Mohammad how about if this is the text <p>11 22&nbsp; 33</p><p>44</p>5<br></div>

Comment: Hi @Mohammad sorry I remove to accept your answer but what if that is the case? thanks

Comment: @howardtyler. No fair changing the question after it's been answered...

Comment: alright will ask the question again thanks @MikeMcCaughan