# Basic Javascript Exercise

Tags: javascript

This is my first question on Stack, so please excuse me if I'm not asking this correctly.

I'm trying to solve a basic exercise that asks me to create a function named countCharacters that accepts two parameters, a character and a string. It should return the number of times the character is present in the string. This is what I have so far:

```
function countCharacters(char, string) {

     return string.indexOf(char);

}
```

Please let me know where I went wrong. I'm still learning basic JavaScript and I appreciate any and all feedback!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679576/counting-words-in-string

Comment: Your  function will return the index of the character in the string. That is the first position it is found.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method you can think of is to use a loop, which checks every character, and updates a counter:

```js
console.log(countCharacters('a', 'abbabaa'));

function countCharacters(char, string) {
    var counter = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<string.length; i++){
        if(string[i] === char){ counter++; }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

You can also use regex to remove any character that is not the one, and return the new length:

```js
console.log(countCharacters('a', 'abbabaa'));

function countCharacters(char, string) {
    var regex = new RegExp('[^' + char + ']', 'g');
    return string.replace(regex,'').length;
}
```

... or use `filter`:

```js
console.log(countCharacters('a', 'abbabaa'));

function countCharacters(char, string) {
  return string.split('').filter(c => c===char).length;
}
```

In your code, you are using `indexOf`, which returns the position of the first occurence of the character. It does not count them.

Answer (score -1):

The thing you're doing wrong is that you're finding the position of the char instead of the number of times it has occured in the string. Please note that `string.indexOf(char);` gives you the index (position) of the occurence of `char` in your `string`.

Comment: @Dave2e the OP asked "Please let me know where I went wrong" and I've answered where he went wrong. The question is already marked duplicate (after I had already answered). I shall update my answer nevertheless.