# Count words dynamically as users types in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

1. I want to take count of words, as user types in the textarea
2. If he/she crosses more than 100 words he/she should  not be allowed to type.
3. I need to dynamically display word count as he/she types

**sample.component.ts**

```
 wordCounter(){
    this.wordCount = this.text ? this.text.split(/\s+/)  : 0;
    this.words=this.wordCount ? this.wordCount.length:0;

  }
```

**This is my function to count words**

**sample.component.html**

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="text" ng-change="wordCounter()" id="wmd-input" name="post-text" class="wmd-input s-input bar0 js-post-body-field processed" data-post-type-id="2" cols="92" rows="15" tabindex="101" data-min-length="" oncopy="return false;" onpaste="return false;" oncut="return false;"></textarea>

<div>Words:<span id="wordCount">{{ words }}</span></div>
```

**This is my html code
Please guide me in doing this. Thanks in advance**

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679576/counting-words-in-string

Comment: Thanks @MikeS. ,but I need to display the wordcount as the user types on the screen to let him know how many words he has already typed. Can I achieve this with ngonchanges(). I don't no how to do that. I'm new to angular

Comment: You can bind to `this.wordCount` anywhere in your template to display the word count. E.g. `<div>{{ wordCount }}</div>`. Same with `this.words`, whatever you need to display.

Comment: <div>Words: <span id="wordCount">{{ wordCount }}</span></div>                          
 Yes did that, but wordcount is not incremented, it stays at 0

Comment: Then that's a problem with your function, read the link I posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `keydown` event and use `ViewChild` to get text in text area

Updated: if you want to restrict only 100 words, you can add `[attr.disabled]="words >100 ? '' : null"` to disable textarea

HTML

```
 <textarea [attr.disabled]="words >100 ? '' : null" (keydown)="wordCounter()" #text id="wmd-input" name="post-text" 
class="wmd-input s-input bar0 js-post-body-field processed" data-post-type-id="2" cols="92" rows="15" tabindex="101" data-min-length="" oncopy="return false;" onpaste="return false;" oncut="return false;"></textarea>

    <div>Words:<span id="wordCount">{{ words }}</span></div>
```

TS

```
export class AppComponent {
  wordCount: any;

  @ViewChild("text") text: ElementRef;
  words: any;
  wordCounter() {
    //alert(this.text.nativeElement.value)
    this.wordCount = this.text ? this.text.nativeElement.value.split(/\s+/) : 0;
    this.words = this.wordCount ? this.wordCount.length : 0;
  }
}
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-word-count

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks, @Hien Nguyen, but how can I limit the word count. User should be restricted from typing if he/she crosses 100 words. Is there any textarea property like Max length() (which limits character), to limit word count

Comment: One more thing, here if I type more than 100 words, text area is disabled from typing as well as editing. If I want to change some content, I cant do it. How to disable from typing alone?? @Hien Nguyen

Answer (score 3):

You could use Angular Reactive [Form control](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) and use it's [`disable()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable) function to achieve your requirement. Try the following

Controller

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'input-autosize-textarea-example',
  templateUrl: './input-autosize-textarea-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-autosize-textarea-example.css'],
})
export class InputAutosizeTextareaExample implements OnInit {
  public remainingWords = 100;

  public textareaForm = new FormGroup ({
    textinput: new FormControl()
  });

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  wordCounter() {
    this.remainingWords = this.textareaForm.value ? 100 - this.textareaForm.value.textinput.split(/\s+/).length : 100;
    if (this.remainingWords <= 0) {
      this.textareaForm.controls['textinput'].disable();
    }
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<form [formGroup]="textareaForm">
  <textarea 
    formControlName="textinput"
    (keyup)="wordCounter()" 
    id="wmd-input" 
    name="post-text" 
    class="wmd-input s-input bar0 js-post-body-field processed" 
    data-post-type-id="2" 
    cols="92" rows="15" 
    tabindex="101" 
    data-min-length="" 
    oncopy="return false;" 
    onpaste="return false;" 
    oncut="return false;"></textarea>
</form>
<div style="font-style: italic;">
  {{ remainingWords }} words remaining...
</div>
<br>
{{textareaForm?.value | json}}
```

The `?.` operator is called [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) and it is used to make sure the objects are defined before trying to access it's properties.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/textarea-form-g8wdbc?file=app/input-autosize-textarea-example.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much @Michael D. Working perfectly. But how to take word count, instead of character count?

Comment: I mistook words for characters. I've updated the code. Please check if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

check my answer in :- https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-mountain-0vpe3

you just have to do the followig :-

In ***`app.module.ts`*** :-

> 1. `import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms"`
> 2. put `FormsModule` in imports array like this - `imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule]`

Now use ***`ngModel`*** binding in ***`app.component.html`***

```
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>Type below</h2>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myText" placeholder=" type here..." />
  </div>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="wordCount">
    <div>
      Your Text : <span><b> {{myText}} </b></span> <br />
      <br />
      Count: <span><b> {{myText.length}} </b></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Scrrenshot:-

[image: Just check it out]