# Word Count with javascript without input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a word count without any input tag. I want to use just p tag and span tag. How can I make it?

```
<span class="word" id="word">Words Number</span> <p class="any" id="any">Here have some text which I want to count</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting words in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679576/counting-words-in-string)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get value of `p`

```
let countVal = document.getElementById('wordCount');
```

Then, make an array from it by using split(separator)

```
let countArr = countVal.split(" ")
```

Finally, display it in your js

```
document.getElementById('someId').textContent = countArr.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these codes:

For JS:
`document.querySelectorAll('#word')[0].textContent.length`

For Jquery:

```
$("#word").text().length; 
$("#any").text().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have same value for class and id in html , change it if possible
like this

```
<span class="Word" id="word">Words Number</span> <p class="Any" id="any">Here have some text which I want to count</p>
```

Then use this jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var myString = $("#any").text();

var countWord = myString.split(' ').length;

});
```